# Unity character controller character is not freezing when I stop all movement when he wall grabs (he keeps sliding)

Tags: unity-game-engine, state-machine

Hey guys I'm learning how to create a character controller via the state pattern, which is pretty snazzy, but I'm running into this weird error

I've got a state machine pattern put together so this should be pretty straightforward and easy to handle, but it's kinda confusing. I tried freezing him in the state to see if he was transitioning from wallgrab to wallslide, but when I stop the velocity on the x and y he still slides. There's no other movement physics being applied at this time (why I'd recommend the state pattern), but for some reason his movement isn't being frozen. I can't pin a reason as to why, other than point you to my code and my github, and hope someone like my pixel art and has fun with the movement for a little bit.

All the code is in the scripts folder within the assets folder, and the states are within Assets > Scripts > Player > and then there are two folders (sub and super) The WallGrabState inherits from the PlayerTouchingWallState, and the logic is coming mainly from the WallGrabState for the physics. I'm just setting the x and y to zero, and yet he still slides, and idk what to do.

PlayerTouchingWall inherits the main state logic from playerState, and the player script loads all the states together and holds the physics and miscellaneous functions. The link to my github project is here https://github.com/roninMo/2d-Intro-Unity-Project

Here's the PlayerWallSlideState:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerWallSlideState : PlayerTouchingWallState
{
    public PlayerWallSlideState(Player player, PlayerStateMachine stateMachine, PlayerData playerData, string currentAnimation) : base(player, stateMachine, playerData, currentAnimation)
    {
    }


    public override void LogicUpdate()
    {
        base.LogicUpdate();

        player.SetVelocityY(-playerData.wallslideVelocity);

        // State logic
        if (grabInput && input.y > 0)
        {
            player.StateMachine.ChangeState(player.wallGrabState);
        }
    }
}
```

And Here's the PlayerTouchingWallState:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerTouchingWallState : PlayerState
{
    protected bool isTouchingGround;
    protected bool isTouchingWall;
    protected Vector2 input;
    protected bool grabInput;

    public PlayerTouchingWallState(Player player, PlayerStateMachine stateMachine, PlayerData playerData, string currentAnimation) : base(player, stateMachine, playerData, currentAnimation)
    {
    }


    public override void Enter()
    {
        base.Enter();
    }


    public override void Exit()
    {
        base.Exit();
    }


    public override void LogicUpdate()
    {
        base.LogicUpdate();

        input = player.InputHandler.RawMovementInput;
        grabInput = player.InputHandler.GrabInput;

        // State logic
        if (isTouchingGround && !grabInput)
        {
            StateMachine.ChangeState(player.IdleState);
        }
        else if (!isTouchingWall || (input.x != player.FacingDirection && !grabInput))
        {
            StateMachine.ChangeState(player.InAirState);
        }
    }


    public override void PhysicsUpdate()
    {
        base.PhysicsUpdate();
    }


    public override void DoChecks()
    {
        base.DoChecks();
        isTouchingGround = player.CheckIfTouchingGround();
        isTouchingWall = player.CheckIfTouchingWall();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that unity still applys physics to the character. I stopped it by grabbing the transform, and setting the player the position it entered in this state, along with freezing the velocity. Setting the transform is enough, but the camera was dragging upwards in place... So freezing the velocity fixed that. Anyways here's the code:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerWallGrabState : PlayerTouchingWallState
{
    private Vector2 holdPosition;

    public PlayerWallGrabState(Player player, PlayerStateMachine stateMachine, PlayerData playerData, string currentAnimation) : base(player, stateMachine, playerData, currentAnimation)
    {
    }


    public override void Enter()
    {
        base.Enter();

        holdPosition = player.transform.position;
        HoldPosition();
    }


    public override void Exit()
    {
        base.Exit();
    }


    public override void LogicUpdate()
    {
        base.LogicUpdate();

        HoldPosition();

        // State logic
        if (input.y > 0)
        {
            StateMachine.ChangeState(player.wallClimbState);
        }
        else if (input.y < 0 || !grabInput)
        {
            StateMachine.ChangeState(player.wallSlideState);
        }
    }


    public override void PhysicsUpdate()
    {
        base.PhysicsUpdate();
    }


    public override void DoChecks()
    {
        base.DoChecks();
    }


    private void HoldPosition()
    {
        player.transform.position = holdPosition;

        player.SetVelocityX(0f);
        player.SetVelocityY(0f);
    }
}
```